Dynamically call the import sentence
I want to switch the libraary by some conditione such as,
if (mode == 'dev'){
    import EditTools from './EditToolsDevTest'
}
else {
    import EditTools from './EditTools'
}

However this shows
An import declaration can only be used at the top level of a module

I guess if C it can be done by using #define
Is there any equivalent for javascript?

use this instead

Witch are you using Webpack or vite.js?
